# Split pandas dataframe into two dataframes based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to search on Stackoverflow for the answer to this and while there are similar answers, I have tried to adapt the accepted answers and I'm struggling to achieve the result I want.

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':
                     ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                          'Sales':
                     [100, 200, 300, 400],
                          'Cost':
                     [2.25, 2.50, 2.10, 3.00]})
```

and another one:

```
split = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':
                 ['B', 'D']})
```

I want to create two new dataframes from the original dataframe df, one containing the data from the split dataframe and the other one containing data, not in the split. I need the original structure of df to remain in both of the newly created dataframes.

I have explored isin, merge, drop and loops but there must be an elegant way to what appears to be a simple solution?

Comment: How about using `join` ? You should be able to do your separation with a join on "Customer". Try it and if you don't succeed, update your question with your attempt;

Comment: Thanks for the steer. I have tried result = pd.merge(df, split, on='Customer', how='outer') but it returns the same results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering, `~` is for inverse boolen mask:

```
mask = df['Customer'].isin(split['Customer'])

df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
  Customer  Sales  Cost
1        B    200   2.5
3        D    400   3.0

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
  Customer  Sales  Cost
0        A    100  2.25
2        C    300  2.10
```

Another solution, also working if need match multiple columns with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (if no parameter `on` it join by all columns), use outer join with `indicator` parameter:

```
df4 = df.merge(split, how='outer', indicator=True)
print (df4)
  Customer  Sales  Cost     _merge
0        A    100  2.25  left_only
1        B    200  2.50       both
2        C    300  2.10  left_only
3        D    400  3.00       both
```

And again filtering by different masks:

```
df11 = df4[df4['_merge'] == 'both']
print (df11)
  Customer  Sales  Cost _merge
1        B    200   2.5   both
3        D    400   3.0   both

df21 = df4[df4['_merge'] == 'left_only']
print (df21)
  Customer  Sales  Cost     _merge
0        A    100  2.25  left_only
2        C    300  2.10  left_only
```

Comment: slightly off topic @jezrael but rather than splitting out into two dataframes could you use a similar approach to create a new column in df and have "in split" / "not in split" populated accordingly in the new column?

Comment: @Ron Use `df['new'] = np.where(mask, "in split", "not in split")`